# Из-за чего может не подключаться языковый пакет на opencart?

Tags: opencart, cms, интернет-магазин

Скачал языковый пакет, забросил его на сервер, потом зашёл в админку интернет-магазина на opencart и добавил этот язык. В результате он появился в списке языков, но при желании переключение не происходит. Остаётся дальше английский. Из-за чего это может быть? За раннее благодарю за любую помощь.